# Dropping duplicates based on two columns and keeping the occurrence based on another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b','a', 'a', 'c', 'a'],
    'col2': ['x1', 'y1','x2', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2'],
    'col3': [1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3],
    'col4': ['m', 'n', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'n']
})
```

I want to drop duplicate columns based on two columns of `col1` and `col4` and keep the one that has highest value on `col3`. The result should look like:

```
  col1 col2  col3 col4
0    b   y1     2    n
1    a   x2     5    m
2    c   x2     3    m
3    a   x2     3    n
```

I tried `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col4'])` by default this keeps the first occurrence. Also if I do `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col4'], keep='last')` it returns a wrong result as the last occurrence doesn't have the highest value in `col3`. I wonder how does one tackle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first sort your values by `col3` then `drop_duplicates` and make use of the `subset` argument and `keep` which we will set to last.

```
df1 = df.sort_values('col3').drop_duplicates(subset=['col1','col4'],keep='last')

print(df1)

  col1 col2  col3 col4
1    b   y1     2    n
4    c   x2     3    m
5    a   x2     3    n
2    a   x2     5    m
```

Another method could be to use `groupby` with `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['col1','col4'])['col3'].idxmax()]

  col1 col2  col3 col4
2    a   x2     5    m
5    a   x2     3    n
1    b   y1     2    n
4    c   x2     3    m
```